# Make Auto and Manual ScrollTop() works without conflicts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing `scrolltop` when the document is ready, that's work, but I'm giving the same script to a div to make the scroll manual. The problem is, if I use the auto-scroll, the manual scroll doesn't work.

**Manual scroll**

```
$("#flecha-inscripciones").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#formInscripciones").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

With:

```
<div id="flecha-inscripciones"><img src="https://residenciarucab.es/img/arrow-down.png" alt="Baja para ver" title="Baja para ver"></div>
```

**Autoscroll:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('html, body').delay(5000).animate({
        scrollTop: $("#formInscripciones").offset().top
    }, 1100);
});
```

You can see example [here](https://residenciarucab.es/inscripciones).

It only works the auto-scroll because the manual scroll has conflict.

Comment: $("#flecha-inscripciones") Is the div with links, which lead to page reload to url

Comment: This div don't work if I have the Auto Scroll, if I remove it, it works, but I want to have both working.

Comment: Both will work only you need to place $("#flecha-inscripciones") Div below the slider, since slider is overlapping down arrow icon

Comment: Well, it's not a problem of positioning the html, because the arrow only works when the auto scroll finished. Check it, If u wait the auto scroll finished, go scroll up and click the arrow, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with queue: false; after the code.

Answer (score -1):

Put below code at end of your, but before that include jquery.js file

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#flecha-inscripciones").click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#formInscripciones").offset().top
      }, 2000);
    });
     $('html, body').delay(5000).animate({
        scrollTop: $("#formInscripciones").offset().top
     }, 1100);
});
```

Comment: Here the query is not related to multiple jquery conflict. He is not able to execute click event